# How can we improve Firebase ML kit text-recognition output result on-device?

Tags: android, firebase, ocr, firebase-mlkit

I am trying to integrate an OCR into mobile devices to extract numbers from images. To do so, I decided to use **Firebase ml kit** since it provides an on-device solution (really helpful when you do not have internet connection to communicate with APIs).

I integrated **Firebase ml kit** into my app and I use *getOnDeviceTextRecognizer()* function to do the OCR part but the result returned is not good at all.

As you can see on the example, the results are poor even if you have a rather good image provided as input.

[image]

This is the sample code used to run the OCR (really similar to the one provided on the official documentation)

```
public class PictureActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        try {
            FirebaseVisionImage image = FirebaseVisionImage.fromFilePath(getApplicationContext(), Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.drawable.test2));
            recognizeText(image);

        } catch(IOException ex){
            Log.d("exception","test");
        }
    }

    private void recognizeText(FirebaseVisionImage image) {

        // [START get_detector_default]
        FirebaseVisionTextRecognizer detector = FirebaseVision.getInstance()
                .getOnDeviceTextRecognizer();
        // [END get_detector_default]

        // [START run_detector]
        Task<FirebaseVisionText> result =
                detector.processImage(image)
                        .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<FirebaseVisionText>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(FirebaseVisionText firebaseVisionText) {
                                // Task completed successfully
                                // [START_EXCLUDE]
                                // [START get_text]
                                for (FirebaseVisionText.TextBlock block : firebaseVisionText.getTextBlocks()) {
                                    Rect boundingBox = block.getBoundingBox();
                                    Point[] cornerPoints = block.getCornerPoints();
                                    String text = block.getText();
                                    Log.d("TESTING", text);
                                    setContentView(R.layout.activity_picture);
                                    TextView output = findViewById(R.id.outputResult);
                                    output.setText(text);

                                    for (FirebaseVisionText.Line line: block.getLines()) {
                                        // ...
                                        for (FirebaseVisionText.Element element: line.getElements()) {
                                            // ...
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                                // [END get_text]
                                // [END_EXCLUDE]
                            }
                        })
                        .addOnFailureListener(
                                new OnFailureListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                        // Task failed with an exception
                                        // ...
                                    }
                                });
        // [END run_detector]
    }
```

I am wondering if there are some parameters we have the possibility to change to optimize the OCR for our case like you can do with tesseract for instance. I checked the documentation but I did not find any helpful suggestion.

In addition, I am not focused on Firebase ml kit. So, if you have other suggestions that can work on mobiles devices (without doing requests to internet APIs) feel free to share.

**Tesseract** was a good alternative but all android wrappers found are not maintained anymore.

Comment: Hi @Loic, Any work around?

Comment: Hello  not really .the offline model is really restrictive. You can improve à bit the results but applying image transformation but it is not the panacea.

Comment: You can instead create your own model and see if it is working better. But as I mentioned in the answer proposed reaching 99% on this type of problem is over optimistic or your model does not represent a real case scenario

Answer (score 0):

Try to use  cloud-based mode ,
FirebaseVisionTextRecognizer detector = FirebaseVision.getInstance()
        .getCloudTextRecognizer();

and if you have specific type of images then you can make a custom machine learning models and upload that model to firebase then you will get 99 % of accuracy.

for details check bellow link
https://firebase.google.com/docs/ml-kit/android/use-custom-models

Comment: As I mentioned the Cloud-based solution does not fit my needs since I looked for an on-device solution. Concerning the custom model it is another solution but saying 99% is over optimistic excepts if you over fit your model...